# Storing in data class

Tags: java

How can I create a data Model class ? , The data will be stored in an `ArrayList`. The array will store 4 pieces  of data `[ID,NAME,AGE,Gender]`. the data will be sent to this class from `JTextField`.

I'm also willing to use vector instead of ArrayList.

I've tried looking for example but I can't seem to find any that I can use for reference.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom Class and implements `Comparable` interface write your sorting logic. Insert all data to List. sort it by `Collections.sort(list)`;

```
class User implements Comparable<User>{
    private String name;
    private long id;
    private Date age;
    private boolean gender;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(User user1) {
        return this.age.compareTo(user1.age);
    }
} 

List<User> users = new ArrayList();
users.add(user);
...
Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: Why do you use the wrappers for the primitive types?

Comment: Wrapper can make life harder as well (null pointers). Plus they imply boxing/unboxing which takes performance. I also wonder about memory consumption.

Comment: A +1 anyway for the nice example ;)